# How to increase array size dynamically without using any built-in function?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-arrays

While using Java, I try not to use any API or built-in method. Is there any way to increase an array's size dynamically without copying it to some other location?

Comment: No there isn't. You will have to allocate another array.

Comment: why not use standard java API?

Comment: No, I suggest you look at the ArrayList implementation  : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java. If you want easily extensible data structure, use a linked list.

Comment: You can use some dynamic structure. For example, allocate an array of size "n", and every time you need to expand it by "n", just allocate another array of size "n", and make the first obe point to the next (linked list of arrays)

Answer (score 1):

You can't increase an array's size. Your only option is to create a new, larger, array and copy the old array's content to it. BTW, this is how `ArrayList` "grows" its internal array.